# IEnumerable and IQueryable, which one does it use when I use the var keyword?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

I have read about IEnumerable and IQueryable, I have read that IQueryable is better with linq because when you use where clauses it creates the exact query it needs, but with IEnumerable it retrieves all rows from database and then filters on memory.

The exact question here: 
Is this the same?

How is the better way?

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var positions = unitOfWork.PositionRepository.Find(p => p.PositionID != null);

            return View(positions.ToList());
        }

 public ActionResult Index()
        {

            IQueryable<positions> positions = unitOfWork.PositionRepository.Find(p => p.PositionID != null);

            return View(positions.ToList());
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var` means that the type is automatically inferred by the compiler. Basically, if the data source is an `IQueryable` (e.g. an Entity Framework or Linq to SQL datacontext, a RIA service, etc), your variable will also be an `IQueryable`. If the data source is an `IEnumerable` (e.g. an in-memory collection of objects), your variable will also be an `IEnumerable`.

Since `IQueryable<T>` inherits from `IEnumerable<T>`, any `IQueryable` can be treated as an `IEnumerable`, by using the `AsEnumerable` extension method. Everything that follows the call to `AsEnumerable` will be executed locally rather than translated to the data source language (SQL, HTTP REST...).